# Suspend stopped working

Tags: 12.10, suspend

I have an Asus X201E netbook with Ubuntu 12.10.

A few weeks ago, Suspend stopped working, either when closing the lid or when calling it manually. It just locks the display, and that's it. I managed to make "suspend" work again SOMETIMES by adding GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs" to /etc/default/grub.conf, but it works only once in a session - the next time this is tried, it fails like before.

This used to work perfectly when I installed the OS in February 2013.

Comment: Some people report success with two solutions in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1157435). Check for the newest [bios](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=483&m=X201E&os=8&hashedid=IVotBp2Edz4XzX1Q) dated March, 2013 (although they don't mention suspend). It's strange that it was working and then stopped. Do you have a new peripheral? Did you notice this after an upgrade or some installation?

Comment: You might also look at [Understanding Suspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend) and [DebugginKernelSuspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend). Suspend/Resume issues are difficult because they involve hardware and many different processes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing a script for USB3 that prevent the suspend:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/pm/sleep.d/moved
sudo mv /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_usb_s3 /etc/pm/sleep.d/moved/
```

It works immediatly.

Bye

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Doesn't work for me unfortunately.